# SP list calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula

Trying to make SP List calculated field for three sites. Each site has two conditions.

Using statement:

```
IF(AND([Site_induction]= "Chester TCC" , [Speed_limit]= "5mph"), "1",
IF(AND([Site_induction]= "Manchester TCC" & [Speed_limit]= "10mph"), "1","0",
IF(AND([Site_induction]= "Liverppol TCC" & [Speed_limit]= "10mph"), "1","0")))
```

This throwing error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below formula:

```
IF(AND([Site_induction] = "Chester TCC", [Speed_limit] = "5mph"), "1", IF(AND([Site_induction] = "Manchester TCC", [Speed_limit]= "10mph"), "1", IF(AND([Site_induction] = "Liverppol TCC", [Speed_limit] = "10mph"), "1", "0")))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).